# How do I get access to the OAuth2 plugin views in CakePHP 2.x?

Tags: php, cakephp, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement a REST API in cakephp.
I download the CakePHP OAuth2 Server Plugin https://github.com/seddonmedia/cakephp-oauth-server

and now i am trying to test it in order to understand how it works.
I use all the default settings and i configured the routes as the documentation propose.
My problem is that every time i try to get access to a view where the oauth component is used i received the below json.
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"No client id supplied"}

I am trying to get access to login page (default login view from plug in) [oauth/login]
and i receive the same error.

Why ? 
How can i get access to login page in order to fill the user's credentials?
Is there any tutorial where i can learn further details?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can read, this plugin needs you to install a Vendor, a Controller Component and finally the plugin it self.

Once done that, remember to load the plugin or load All the plugins in Config/bootstrap.php file.

```
CakePlugin::loadAll();
```

Then just: http://yourwebsite.com/oauth

Although, the provided oauth controller is like a demo, not intended for you to use it that way, you should have your own users controller where you should have your own login and authorise functions for your APPs flow.

Outside the plugin, in your users controller load the component:

```
public $components = array('OAuth.OAuth', 'Auth', 'Session', 'Security');
```

In beforeFilter add:

```
$this->OAuth->authenticate = array('fields' => array('username' => 'email'));
```

**Then, you can just copy the login function on the oath controller of the plugin.**